# iOS Localizable.strings file for XIB files?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, localization, localizable.strings

I'm translating an iOS project into Portuguese and I've created a pt.lproj/Localizable.strings file, and I've added NSLocalizedString() into the source code. It all works! With one slight problem - the strings within XIB files don't get translated... I know this is by design though.

I've seen that the ibtool command can be used to rip strings from an XIB file called x and put it into a file called x.strings... but my question is, is there a way to pull the strings from ALL the xib files and put them all into one .strings file (e.g. Localizable.strings? or even another one called XIBs.strings would be fine?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have two options how to translate xib files. One is you connect the UI elements to outlets and set your strings in your viewDidLoad method using the `NSLocalizedString` macros.

The second option is to provide a separate xib for each language your app supports. You don't have to create them manually, you can use the `ibtool` command (i assume your source language is English and target is Portugese):

```
ibtool --strings-file pt.lproj/Example.strings en.lproj/Example.xib –write pt.lproj/Example.xib
```

To collect strings found in your project you can use `genstrings` command - however i recommend using this [python script](https://bitbucket.org/snej/murky/src/8f5ddf942899/Localize.py) to collect all your strings - it can nicely handle the situation when you need to add/remove strings to your app without having to translate and/or manually merge all previous strings

**Edit**

Oh and i found the [article](http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/iphone-applications-localization-guide/) that i learned this trick from

Comment: Okay, so there's not a super simple way to do it! I think I going to do the IBOutlets route, as there are about 40 nib files, but some strings are shared between them (and we want about 10 languages eventually so it'll be better in the long run I think!) I guess I'll just go through the NIBs and make sure the labels etc can accommodate a bit more text for other languages (otherwise layout will be identical)! Anyways, thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 3):

I made a category to do this:

```
@implementation UIView (Localise)

- (void)localise
{
    [self.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(UIView *view, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [view localise];
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
            UILabel *label = (UILabel *)view;
            [label setText:NSLocalizedString(label.text, nil)];
        }
    }];
}
```

Then in your views:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self localise];
}
```

You'll need to add support for other UI elements (textField.placeholder = NSLocal...blah blah), but that'll do the trick for UILabel and children.

Probably not great performance-wise but does the job.

Answer (score 0):

It's going to depend on the app and the number of localizations, but in general I prefer separate .xib files, because layout may change. Put the localized files in pt.lproj/.